# How to know if subtitle is two or more lines long in a SwitchListTile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There is a property called `isThreeLine` in `SwitchListTile`. I would like to set its value to `true` only if my subtitle is two or more lines long. How do I know that?

```
SwitchListTile(
  value: true,
  title: Text('Title'),
  subtitle: Text('This is going to be a subtitle which is two lines long with isThreeLine: true'),
  isThreeLine: false, // only set it to true when my subtitle is 2 or more lines long. 
  onChanged: null,
)
```

[image]

[image]

---

Note: I'm not looking for any workarounds like playing with the total length of string etc.

Comment: What problem are you facing with it's normal behavior?

Comment: @PratyushTiwari As you can see if my subtitle is longer than a line, I get very little room but when I set `isThreeLine: true`, it looks good.

Comment: If you are looking for an out of the box solution that will do the "magic" of "playing" around for you, then nope, afaik there is none heh. If you wanna "play" you can take a look at [LineMetrics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/LineMetrics-class.html) and this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-line-metrics-fd98ab180a64) on medium. If that is not your cup of tea, then I suggest either using SwitchListTile as it is or approaching the problem differently (like instead using a column,row,switch,align etc.), will be more code but that is the price to get it exactly how you want it.